# Set() method is not working right

Tags: java

folks, my set(T f) has to change the current `this.element` of the my 2D Arraylist but it's not doing this. For example, if I have this:

```
Board<Object> board = new Board<Object>(3,9,2,6,"??");
System.out.println(board.toString());
board.setFillElem(".");
System.out.println(board);
```

The outputs are:

```
    |  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  3 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  4 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  5 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  6 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  7 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  8 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  9 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+

    |  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  3 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  4 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  5 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  6 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  7 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  8 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  9 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

The internal element `??` did not change to what was `set()`, i.e. it was not set to `"."`. Could smb help me out here with the `set(T f)` method considering that the complexity is `O(1)`? Thanks!
     public void setFillElem(T f){
          this.element = f;

```
  }
```

Comment: You'll have to refill the board

Comment: @MadProgrammer, but will it be in terms of O(1)? Or if I create a private method and call it from set(), will it still be considered O(1)?

Comment: I have no idea, but if your want to change what value is used to as the fill element, you will need to replace all the values in you board again

Comment: A "cheat" might be to have an `Object` which acts as the "filler", but which takes the value to actually be used via a variable.  You would then create a single instance of this "fill" object and simply change it's variable.  This means that when you display the board again, the "fill" object hasn't changed, but the value you use has

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling ´setFillElem´ after you've already populated `myBoard`.  I suggest you split out the population code into a separate method from the constructor, and call it from both the constructor and `setFillElem`.

```
private int minRow;
private int maxRow;
private int minCol;
private int maxCol;
private T element;

public Board(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T fillElem){
    this.minRow = minRow;
    this.maxRow = maxRow;
    this.minCol = minCol;
    this.maxCol = maxCol;

    if(fillElem == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot set elements to null");
    }
    else {
        this.element = fillElem;
    }

    myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    populateBoard();
}

public void setFillElem(T f){
    this.element = f;
    populateBoard();
    //this = new DenseBoard(minRow, maxRow, minCol, maxCol, f);
}

private void populateBoard() {
    // empty existing elements
    myBoard.clear();

    if((minRow >= 0 && maxRow >=0) && (minCol >= 0 && maxCol >= 0)){
        int row = maxRow - minRow;
        int col = maxCol - minCol;
        ArrayList<T> rowLine;
        for(int i = 0; i <= row; i++){
            rowLine = new ArrayList<T>();
            myBoard.add(rowLine);
            for(int j = 0; j <= col; j++){
                rowLine.add(j, this.element);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, @SteveChaloner, I'll take your response in account. But is creating a private method in terms of O(1)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you could "cheat".

Basically, you create a "wrapper" around the actual value for any given cell.  When you initialize the `List`, you create a single instance of this wrapper class and give it the filler value, you add this to each and ever cell.

When you need to, you simply change the value the fill cell contains, for example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board(3, 9, 2, 6, "??");
        System.out.println(b);
        b.setFillElem(".");
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static class Board<T> {

        private int minRow;
        private int maxRow;
        private int minCol;
        private int maxCol;
        private Cell fillCell;
        private final ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> myBoard;

        public Board(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T fillElem) {
            this.minRow = minRow;
            this.maxRow = maxRow;
            this.minCol = minCol;
            this.maxCol = maxCol;

            if (fillElem == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot set elements to null");
            } else {
                fillCell = new Cell(fillElem);
            }

            myBoard = new ArrayList<>();
            if ((minRow >= 0 && maxRow >= 0) && (minCol >= 0 && maxCol >= 0)) {
                int row = maxRow - minRow;
                int col = maxCol - minCol;
                ArrayList<Cell> rowLine;
                for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
                    rowLine = new ArrayList<>();
                    myBoard.add(rowLine);
                    for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++) {
                        rowLine.add(j, fillCell);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void setFillElem(T f) {
            fillCell.setValue(f);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringJoiner header = new StringJoiner("|", "", "|\n");
            header.add("    ");
            String dash = String.format("%1$3s", "").replaceAll(" ", "-");
            StringJoiner lineSep = new StringJoiner("+", "", "+\n");
            lineSep.add("    ");
            for (int col = minCol; col < maxCol + 1; col++) {
                header.add(String.format("%3d", col));
                lineSep.add(dash);
            }

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(128);
            result.append(header);
            result.append(lineSep);
            for (int row = 0; row < myBoard.size(); row++) {
                ArrayList<Cell> rowLine = myBoard.get(row);
                result.append(String.format("%3d |", minRow + row));
                StringJoiner rj = new StringJoiner("|", "", "|\n");
                for (Cell cell : rowLine) {
                    rj.add(String.format("%1$3s", cell.getValue().toString()));
                }
                result.append(rj.toString());
                result.append(lineSep);
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

        protected class Cell {

            private T value;

            public Cell(T value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public T getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(T value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
    |  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  3 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  4 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  5 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  6 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  7 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  8 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  9 | ??| ??| ??| ??| ??|
    +---+---+---+---+---+

    |  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  3 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  4 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  5 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  6 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  7 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  8 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
  9 |  .|  .|  .|  .|  .|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

The trick here is to ALWAYS use the instance of `fillCell` when you need to make a cell empty.

Comment: Love the way you wrote the code! Thanks! Btw, what does it do: `String.format("%3d |", minRow + row)` ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: It writes the row label with at least spaces (so you can it to print up to 999 and all the values below 100 will be left padded)